# mode.evaluate() on keras gives the same network accuracy after the weights are modified using set_weights methods?

Tags: keras

I am trying to compare the accuracy of a trained sequential MLP model before and after changing the weights using set_weights() function. For some reason, although the weights can change, when I run the model.evaluate() function, I get the same results, suggesting the model does not seem to using the new weights. Here is some code..

```
print("Size of First Layer Weights", np.shape(W12))
print("Size of Second Layer Weights", np.shape(W21))
loss_and_metrics = mnist_model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=2)
print("Test Loss", loss_and_metrics[0])
print("Test Accuracy", loss_and_metrics[1])

# Performance with New Weights 
W12_New=W12_PCM.reshape(1, 784, 256)
W21_New=W21_PCM.reshape(1, 256, 10)
layer_1.set_weights(W12_New)
layer_2.set_weights(W21_New)

print("Size of First Layer Updated Weights", np.shape(W12_New))
print("Size of Second Layer Updated Weights", np.shape(W21_New))
loss_and_metrics = mnist_model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=2)
print("Test Loss Under Updated Weights", loss_and_metrics[0])

Size of First Layer Weights (1, 784, 256)
Size of Second Layer Weights (1, 256, 10)
313/313 - 0s - loss: 0.0726 - accuracy: 0.9773
Test Loss 0.07255715876817703
Test Accuracy 0.9772999882698059
Size of First Layer Updated Weights (1, 784, 256)
Size of Second Layer Updated Weights (1, 256, 10)
313/313 - 0s - loss: 0.0726 - accuracy: 0.9773
Test Loss Under Updated Weights 0.07255715876817703
Test Accuracy Under Updated Weights 0.9772999882698059
```

Comment: What exact change are you doing to the weights?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy: In this example, I am rounding off the matrix elements to double digits after the decimal. But eventually I want to try a few cases where I scale the weight distributions by some constant scalar.

Comment: You need to include that code, also note that rounding might not affect predictions much, specially if you apply the same transformation to all weights.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Snoopy. But the predictions do not change even if I set the weights to very different values.  If I were to change line 7 of the above code to W12_new = np.zeros((1,784,256)), and set this as new weight for the first later, the results do not alter. The model.evaluate() still takes the original weights

Comment: Again, you need to include code that reproduces the problem, not partial views of your code.